# Apache Child process consume huge memory

Tags: php, apache, memory

"top" shows the result of how httpd-Child-process consume the memory.
most Child process uses 400MB. I think this is too huge.

Usually, I know Child process consume the memory at most 50MB.

Do you know any good way to know why the child process uses huge memory?

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1039 nobody    20   0 32.7g 412m  55m S  0.0  0.3   0:50.76 httpd
10366 nobody    20   0 32.7g 411m  54m S  0.0  0.3   1:11.28 httpd
16115 nobody    20   0 32.7g 410m  53m S  0.0  0.3   0:44.23 httpd
26472 nobody    20   0 32.7g 410m  52m S  0.0  0.3   0:45.95 httpd
・・・・
・・・・
```

Answer (score 0):

If the child processes are actively running and handling a large script, like a data import or something, then they might be holding a lot of data in memory while they run. It really depends on how scripts are running.

Typically, if Apache is handing off a request to a module like PHP or something (you have php as a tag on this question), it's the responsibility of that scripting engine to enforce some common-sense limits to things like memory usage or time limits to prevent people from creating scripts that try to suck up all the server's resources.

I would suggest trying to trace these child workers back to the specific requests to confirm that they are just out-of-control PHP scripts or something, then search the content of those scripts to see if they try to override any limits (like set_time_limit(0) or ini_set("memory_limit",...)). If they do, then you will have to talk to the developer of the scripts to figure out if they're really needed (e.g. maybe the developer is reading in a huge data file all at once and keeping it in memory instead of reading it in small chunks).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll continue to solve this issue. 
on the other hand,  i figured out that why virt size is big. 
the cause was apc.shm_size in php.ini. apc.shm_size was too big.